# Strange JSON behaviour with accentuated characters

Tags: php, android, json

I have an Android app writing text into an external database. Let's play with the text: **frodå**

In short this is how I forward the code to the server:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", name_et.getText().toString()));
JSONParser jsonParser; jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(insert_username, "POST", params);
```

The problem is that however, the PHP script receives the text correctly (I send it to myself in mail and the text **frodå** is received), but only **frod** is written into the database.

When I manually run the script by entering it in the browser with `$user_name = 'frodå';` instead of `$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];` then the text is correctly written into the database. How is this possible???

This is the php script:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
require_once($_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'].'dbauth.php');
include("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$response = array();

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response = '0';
}
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];

try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE APPUSERS SET USERNAME=? WHERE USERID=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($user_name, $userID));
    $response["success"] = 1;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response["success"] = 0;
}

    //Then here I use PHPMailer to send the text received by POST to myself to check
 that the POST variable is the correct variable. I receive frodå by mail which means 
the correct text is received, but only frod is written into database. I tried this
 out many times.
```

I can also manually add accentuated characters in the database. The table is encoded as utf8_general_ci.

I think the problem is that the text I forward with JSON in Android is not UTF8 encoded. What do you think? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you found the problem with your last statement; you're not sending UTF8 data to your PHP script.  The following is how I do it.

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.myurl.com");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

And then, when reading the response.

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
    String line = "0";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}
```